# Ruby on Rails gem to make passwords more secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passwords, password-protection

I built a Ruby on Rails authentication system from scratch and it works great.

(I am aware of the existence of `Devise`, yet I wanted to write my own system to get a better grasp of Ruby on Rails in general.)

The only thing that worries me is users who pick words from dictionaries, sequential numbers (e.g. "12345679"), their own user names, or the all-time classic "password" as their own `password`.

Is there a gem that validates against any of those? Or will I have to work with regular expressions here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[stong_password gem](https://github.com/bdmac/strong_password) is really cool. Though it may not contain everything you are looking for, it still is a pretty good gem